# How to change request date in php?

Tags: php, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

This is the sample request date `Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)`

I want to convert to this format `2022-02-19`.

Comment: This request is from the kendo date picker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$begin_date = 'Wed Feb 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0800';
$timestamp = strtotime($begin_date);
$my_date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
echo $my_date;
```